# How to backup a SharePoint list to Excel or CSV so that ‘Choice’ column (with multiple selections) values are displayed as text?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

**Environment**

I created a `Custom List` via `New` > `App` > `Custom List`.

I created columns and added entries via the form associated with the list.

Some of the columns are of type `Choice` and configured to allow multiple selections.

For example:

```
Service Type:  

 - Groceries - Apples
 - Groceries - Oranges   
 - Groceries - General
```

**Desired Behaviour**

Copy a SharePoint list into a CSV file via a recurring Microsoft Flow based on [this template](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/79095f001ee911e79dc3835964ea3218/copy-sharepoint-list-items-into-a-csv-each-week/).

I have only chosen the `CSV` format for the backup because I thought it would be easier to set up the related flow - if an Excel spreadsheet backup could be created, that would be ideal.

**Current Behaviour**

When I open the CSV in Excel, a single Choice column has turned into 4 columns:

```
ServiceType
```

```
ServiceType@odata.type
```

```
ServiceType#Id
```

```
ServiceType#Id@odata.type
```

with the corresponding values of:

```
[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":2,"Value":"Groceries - General"}]
```

```
#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference)
```

```
[2]
```

```
#Collection(Int64)
```

**Question**

How can I ensure that:

- Only a single column is displayed for each Choice column
- Only the *values* of the columns are displayed, rather than all the Microsoft 'markup' text

**Flow:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Use this:

```
xpath(xml(json(concat('{"root":{"choices":', item()?['MyChoiceColumnInternalName'] , '}}'))), '/root/choices/Value/text()')
```

or this:

```
join(xpath(xml(json(concat('{"root":{"choices":', item()?['MyChoiceColumnInternalName'] , '}}'))), '/root/choices/Value/text()'), ';#')
```

**Long Answer**

I thought it would be helpful to:

- create a list that contained all column types
- add an entry
- export the list to CSV table
- see what the exported values were

These are the columns:

> **Edit:**  Things I learned after posting this:
>
> - Column names have a 32 characters limit 'internally', longer names are truncated ([src](http://knappsharepointblog.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-internal-field-names-have-32.html))
> - Changing the column name does not change the 'internal' column name ([src](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Column-names-not-updating-in-collection-with-sharepoint/m-p/51758))

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|                Column                |          Type          |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Title                                | Single line of text    |
| MySingleLineOfTextColumn             | Single line of text    |
| MyMultipleLinesOfTextColumn          | Multiple lines of text |
| MyNumberColumn                       | Number                 |
| MyYesNoColumn                        | Yes/No                 |
| MyPersonColumn                       | Person or Group        |
| MyDateColumn                         | Date and Time          |
| MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelections    | Choice                 |
| MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelections | Choice                 |
| MyChoiceColumnSingleWithSelection    | Choice                 |
| MyChoiceColumnSingleWithoutSelection | Choice                 |
| MyHyperlinkColumn                    | Hyperlink or Picture   |
| MyPictureColumn                      | Hyperlink or Picture   |
| MyCurrencyColumn                     | Currency               |
| MyLocationColumn                     | Location               |
| Modified                             | Date and Time          |
| Created                              | Date and Time          |
| Created By                           | Person or Group        |
| Modified By                          | Person or Group        |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

So first, I switched to the `Custom` option in the `Create CSV Table` section.

The stars below indicate dynamic content variables that had 'extended' versions available because their value is an `object`, not a `string`, ie:

```
MyLocationColumn: Name
MyPersonColumn DisplayName
MyChoiceColumnSingleWithSelection Value 
MyChoiceColumnSingleWithoutSelection Value
Modified By DisplayName 
Created By DisplayName
```

[image]

When I tested the flow, these were the results in the `Create CSV Table` step:

[image]

**JSON** (the `INPUTS > From` section):

The `Get items` step produces an array of objects, where each object is an `item` in the list.

You can see below which columns have a `string`, `object` or `array` as a value.

The column type of `Choice` (multiple selections allowed) has the latter - ie an array of objects.

```
[
  {
    "@odata.etag": "\"6\"",
    "ItemInternalId": "2",
    "ID": 2,
    "Title": "Test",
    "MySingleLineOfTextColumn": "Here is a single line of text",
    "MyMultipleLinesOfTextColumn": "Here\nAre\nMultiple\nLines\nOf\nText",
    "MyNumberColumn": 5,
    "MyYesNoColumn": true,
    "MyPersonColumn": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
      "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "DisplayName": "John Smith",
      "Email": "info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Picture": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mydomain/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Department": null,
      "JobTitle": null
    },
    "MyPersonColumn#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "MyDateColumn": "2020-04-30",
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelection": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 0,
        "Value": "Choice 1"
      },
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 1,
        "Value": "Choice 2"
      },
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 2,
        "Value": "Choice 3"
      }
    ],
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelection@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference)",
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelection#Id": [
      0,
      1,
      2
    ],
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelection#Id@odata.type": "#Collection(Int64)",
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelect": [],
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelect@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference)",
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelect#Id": [],
    "MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelect#Id@odata.type": "#Collection(Int64)",
    "MyChoiceColumnSingleWithSelectio": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
      "Id": 0,
      "Value": "Choice 1"
    },
    "MyChoiceColumnSingleWithSelectio#Id": 0,
    "MyHyperlinkColumn": "https://www.google.com",
    "MyPictureColumn": "https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg",
    "MyCurrencyColumn": 20,
    "CountryOrRegion": "Australia",
    "State": "NSW",
    "City": "Sydney",
    "PostalCode": "2000",
    "Street": "100 Test St",
    "DispName": "100 Test St, Sydney, NSW 2000",
    "Modified": "2020-04-30T08:42:27Z",
    "Created": "2020-04-30T07:17:22Z",
    "Author": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
      "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "DisplayName": "John Smith",
      "Email": "info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Picture": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mydomain/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Department": null,
      "JobTitle": null
    },
    "Author#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Editor": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
      "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "DisplayName": "John Smith",
      "Email": "info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Picture": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mydomain/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "Department": null,
      "JobTitle": null
    },
    "Editor#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|info@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "{Identifier}": "Lists%252fMy%2bAll%2bColumn%2bTypes%2bList%252f2_.000",
    "{IsFolder}": false,
    "{Thumbnail}": {
      "Large": null,
      "Medium": null,
      "Small": null
    },
    "{Link}": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/mydomain/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=5aaeae22-ccf3-48ba-a88b-4130b4293d9f&ID=2&ContentTypeID=0x0100C770D8569664E542BC4A1154C9A4D48E",
    "{Name}": "Test",
    "{FilenameWithExtension}": "Test",
    "{Path}": "Lists/My All Column Types List/",
    "{FullPath}": "Lists/My All Column Types List/2_.000",
    "{HasAttachments}": false,
    "{VersionNumber}": "1.0"
  }
]
```

**Text** (the `OUTPUTS > Body` section):

```
Title,MySingleLineOfTextColumn,MyMultipleLinesOfTextColumn,MyNumberColumn,MyYesNoColumn,MyPersonColumn,MyDateColumn,MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelections,MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelections,MyChoiceColumnSingleWithSelection,MyChoiceColumnSingleWithoutSelection,MyHyperlinkColumn,MyPictureColumn,MyCurrencyColumn,MyLocationColumn,Modified,Modified By,Created,Created By
Test,Here is a single line of text,"Here
Are
Multiple
Lines
Of
Text",5,True,John Smith,2020-04-30,"[{""@odata.type"":""#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"",""Id"":0,""Value"":""Choice 1""},{""@odata.type"":""#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"",""Id"":1,""Value"":""Choice 2""},{""@odata.type"":""#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"",""Id"":2,""Value"":""Choice 3""}]",[],Choice 1,,https://www.google.com,https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg,20,"100 Test St, Sydney, NSW 2000",2020-04-30T08:42:27Z,John Smith,2020-04-30T07:17:22Z,John Smith
```

**Final output displayed in CSV file is therefore:**

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
|                Column                |          Type          |      Output      |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
| Title                                | Single line of text    | Text             |
| MySingleLineOfTextColumn             | Single line of text    | Text             |
| MyMultipleLinesOfTextColumn          | Multiple lines of text | Text             |
| MyNumberColumn                       | Number                 | Text             |
| MyYesNoColumn                        | Yes/No                 | Text             |
| MyPersonColumn                       | Person or Group        | Text***          |
| MyDateColumn                         | Date and Time          | Text             |
| MyChoiceColumnMultiWithSelections    | Choice                 | Array of Objects |
| MyChoiceColumnMultiWithoutSelections | Choice                 | Array (Empty)    |
| MyChoiceColumnSingleWithSelection    | Choice                 | Text***          |
| MyChoiceColumnSingleWithoutSelection | Choice                 | Text***(Blank)   |
| MyHyperlinkColumn                    | Hyperlink or Picture   | Text             |
| MyPictureColumn                      | Hyperlink or Picture   | Text             |
| MyCurrencyColumn                     | Currency               | Text             |
| MyLocationColumn                     | Location               | Text***          |
| Modified                             | Date and Time          | Text             |
| Created                              | Date and Time          | Text             |
| Created By                           | Person or Group        | Text***          |
| Modified By                          | Person or Group        | Text***          |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

*** indicates an 'extended' dynamic variable was used.

**Conclusion**

You can get a text output for most column types, however Choice (multiselection) is different as its value is an array of objects:

```
[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"Choice 1"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"Choice 2"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":2,"Value":"Choice 3"}]
```

Choice columns (without multiple selections allowed) have the dynamic variable `ColumnName Value` available because their value is an object.

**Solution**

Choice column (with multiple selections allowed) can be accessed using an expression like this:

```
xpath(xml(json(concat('{"root":{"choices":', item()?['MyChoiceColumnInternalName'] , '}}'))), '/root/choices/Value/text()')
```

which will produce an array like this (if selections have been made):

```
["Choice 1","Choice 2"]
```

or an empty array if no selections have been made:

```
[]
```

This approach is mentioned in an answer to this post:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-get-multiple-values-from-sharepoint-column-for-CSV-table/td-p/126853

**Explanation of solution**

In case it helps anyone visualising what the `xpath` expression does in the solution provided:

```
var concatenated_string = '{"root":{"choices":' + '[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"Choice 1"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"Choice 2"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":2,"Value":"Choice 3"}]' + '}}'; 

/*

produces a string:

{"root":{"choices":[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"Choice 1"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":1,"Value":"Choice 2"},{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":2,"Value":"Choice 3"}]}}

*/

var json_concatenated_string = JSON.parse(concatenated_string);  

/*

produces an object:

{
  "root": {
    "choices": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 0,
        "Value": "Choice 1"
      },
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 1,
        "Value": "Choice 2"
      },
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 2,
        "Value": "Choice 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}

*/

var my_xml = json2xml(json_concatenated_string); 

/*

produces xml:  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <choices odata.type="#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference">
      <Id>0</Id>
      <Value>Choice 1</Value>
   </choices>
   <choices odata.type="#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference">
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Value>Choice 2</Value>
   </choices>
   <choices odata.type="#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference">
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Value>Choice 3</Value>
   </choices>
</root>
*/


/* 

xpath(xml, '/root/choices/Value/text()')  

get's each Choice's 'Value' property and returns an array of matches, eg:

["Choice 1","Choice 2","Choice 3"] 

see:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xpath  

*/


// function to convert JSON to XML
/*  This work is licensed under Creative Commons GNU LGPL License.

    License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/
   Version: 0.9
    Author:  Stefan Goessner/2006
    Web:     http://goessner.net/ 
*/
function json2xml(o, tab) {
   var toXml = function(v, name, ind) {
      var xml = "";
      if (v instanceof Array) {
         for (var i=0, n=v.length; i<n; i++)
            xml += ind + toXml(v[i], name, ind+"\t") + "\n";
      }
      else if (typeof(v) == "object") {
         var hasChild = false;
         xml += ind + "<" + name;
         for (var m in v) {
            if (m.charAt(0) == "@")
               xml += " " + m.substr(1) + "=\"" + v[m].toString() + "\"";
            else
               hasChild = true;
         }
         xml += hasChild ? ">" : "/>";
         if (hasChild) {
            for (var m in v) {
               if (m == "#text")
                  xml += v[m];
               else if (m == "#cdata")
                  xml += "<![CDATA[" + v[m] + "]]>";
               else if (m.charAt(0) != "@")
                  xml += toXml(v[m], m, ind+"\t");
            }
            xml += (xml.charAt(xml.length-1)=="\n"?ind:"") + "</" + name + ">";
         }
      }
      else {
         xml += ind + "<" + name + ">" + v.toString() +  "</" + name + ">";
      }
      return xml;
   }, xml="";
   for (var m in o)
      xml += toXml(o[m], m, "");
   return tab ? xml.replace(/\t/g, tab) : xml.replace(/\t|\n/g, "");
}
```

**Bonus**

If you want to output this (a value that can be imported *back into* a SharePoint list as a Choice (multiple selections allowed) value):

```
Choice 1;#Choice 2;#Choice 3
```

Wrap the xpath in a [join](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#join):

```
join(xpath(xml(json(concat('{"root":{"choices":', item()?['MyChoiceColumnInternalName'] , '}}'))), '/root/choices/Value/text()'), ';#')
```

Comment: Thank you past self for providing such detailed information about the process and related concerns.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, i will suggest directly [export sharepoint list to excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9)

You can always update the file to the latest list via refresh all, no need to update it everyday.

Comment: Desired behaviour is to copy a SharePoint list into a CSV file via a recurring Microsoft Flow based on [this template from Microsoft](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/79095f001ee911e79dc3835964ea3218/copy-sharepoint-list-items-into-a-csv-each-week/).  An automated process is required, not a manual `Export to Excel`.

Comment: @user1063287 this template uses the action create csv table, it will not meet your requirement.